# Loading Spring Boot controllers after Spring initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, groovy

Our Groovy application works by loading code at runtime. It's a multi-tenant web spring-boot application that contains some Controllers, some simple DI, the usual stuff.

Each tenant is added to our app via external code that is only known at runtime. It works roughly in a "plugin" fashion. Being able to load code at runtime gives us the ability to add, update and remove these plugins/tenants at will and it all makes sense in our context. These tenants are often changed, and restarting our main app everytime we change them is not feasible. So the approach of loading code at runtime works great for us. I'll use the words tenant and plugin somewhat interchangeably, where plugin just means the external code related to the tenant.

Nowadays we load this Groovy code using something like this:

```
GroovyClassLoader classLoader = new GroovyClassLoader()
classLoader.addClasspath(sourceDirectory)
Class clazz = classLoader.loadClass(pluginMainClass)
return clazz.newInstance()
```

The returned type has no Spring stuff, no annotations, and it works just fine, everyone is happy and life is good. Our app knows how to store and use the returned instance.

However, it came to a point where one of those tenants needs a Controller in it. Essentially I want to import some controllers from external plugin code into the main application.

The main application already has some controllers. What we need is to add another controller to the main application. The Groovy code that contains such controller is only known at runtime (we tell the app where to find the source code, essentialy), therefore we can't just add a dependency.

What I've tried is to declare, in the plugin project, a new class that has this code:

```
@Configuration
@Import(ThePluginController)
class ThePluginConfiguration {

}
```

The controller is probably correct:

```
@Controller
@Slf4j
class PanvelController {
    @RequestMapping(path="the-plugin/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    def index(Model model){
      return "index"
    }
}
```

And the main project would load the plugin:

```
void loadConfiguration(ApplicationContext context, ...) 
{
    Class clazz = ... get ThePluginConfiguration class object

    AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowire = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
    BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) autowire
    BeanDefinition definition = new RootBeanDefinition(clazz, Autowire.BY_TYPE.value(), true)
    registry.registerBeanDefinition(clazz.name, definition)
}
```

However, nothing happens. The controller doesn't get registered at all, and I'm probably very confused about stuff. Probably the code I posted doesn't do anything useful, so I'm asking for help.

What should happen is that, when registering the controller, it should start accepting requests to the URL they map to. And also show something like this in the logs:

```
2017-11-17 14:52:42.561  INFO 1692 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/the-plugin/index],methods=[GET]}" onto (package/method) ....
```

This person is trying to do the same thing: [Spring boot: Add new endpoints at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991778/spring-boot-add-new-endpoints-at-runtime)

I also saw some other answers suggesting something like this, but didn't work for me: http://davidwelch.co/java-stack/programmatically-add-controllers-to-spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring, so I don't know exactly what my issue is. Is it even possible to achieve that?

Comment: I think beside registering the bean to the spring, you need to tell SpringMvc about your new controller. This happens at component scan, but that is already passed when you call this method.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to think it's not possible. Or. if it's possible, it's way too hacky. We decided to change our approach to the problem though.

Comment: Have you thought about a "Feature-Toggle"? An [blog entry] (https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/feature-toggle-implementation-using-spring-boot-jonnabhatla) has a sample how to de/activate a condition and path your software shall go. 
This means, that you have already to implement and register the Bean you'd like to use, but your Toggle allows to access methods or not. These toggles could be switched at runtime via Spring Shell. I hope I got you right. Nonetheless I don't know, if Controllers could be loaded after bootstrapping everything.